# Laravel best practices to setup debugbar

Tags: php, laravel, phpdebugbar

I have laravel project, in which I fetch data which are database cursors and the data embedded in them.  I want to inspect the data. What is right setup ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` to your composer.json and if you are setting the environmnet to development, it will appear in the bottom, if you set your environment to production it wil not be shown.

You could find more details in their github repository https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar